# How to drag and drop html element in inner card or box?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I am trying to drag and drop any html element in nested level of container.

[image]

**First level of drag and drop of elements are working but nested level is not working.**

Nested level means "Dropping button inside card element which also an element".
I am taking card as control and container.

I am developing in `reactjs`, `react-dnd`.

Code :

**app.js**

```
const App = props =>{
       const [controlsList, setControlList]= useState([
        { email_txt }, { button }, { card } , {textarea } ...
       ])
    
       return (
              <>
                      <div className="draggable">
                            {
                              controlsList.map(({_id, type, title}, index)=>{
                                 <ControlsAndContainers _id={_id} type={type} title={title} />                                    
                              })
                            } 
                      </div>
                      <div className="droppable">
                            <DropBox/>
                      </div>
              </>
       )
    }
```

**ControlsAndContainer.js**

```
import { useDrag } from 'react-dnd'

const ControlsAndContainer = ({_id, type, title })=>{
  
  const [ {opacity}, drag ] = useDrag(()=>({
      type,
      item: { _id, type, title },
      end: (item, monitor)=>{
         // 
      },
      collect: (monitor) =>({
         opacity: monitor.isDragging()? 0.4 : 1
      })
  }), [title, type]);
  const box_style = {
       cursor: 'move', border: '1px dashed gray'
  }
  return (
     <div ref={drag} style={{ ...box_style, opacity}}>
            {title}
     </div>
  )
}
```

**dropbox.js**

```
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd'
const DropBox = () =>{
     
     let temp =[];
      
     const [dataState, setDataState] = useState([]);

     const [{isOver }, drop] = useDrop(()=> ({
      accept: ['button', 'email', 'card', 'textarea'],
      drop(item, monitor){

          temp.push(item);
          setDataState(temp);
          
      },
      collect:(monitor)=>{
          isOver: monitor.isOver(),          ​
     ​}

    ​}), []);
    
   ​const ButtonControl = () => {
          ​return ( <div> <button>Button</button> </div>)
    ​}
    ​.... email, textarea

    ​// card code is from react-bootsrap
    ​const CardControl = () => {
      ​<Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
         ​<Card.Header>Header</Card.Header>
         ​<Card.Body>
            ​Drop other element here
         ​</Card.Body>
         ​<Card.Footer>Footer</Card.Footer>
       ​</Card>
   ​}
    ​return (
              ​<div ref={drop}>
                   ​dataState.map((data,index)=>{
                           ​let container;
                           ​switch(data.type){
                                  ​case 'button': container=<ButtonControl />
                                  ​break;
                                  ​case 'button': container=<CardControl />
                                  ​break;
                                  ​default: break;
                           ​}
                           ​return (
                                ​<> <div key={data._id}> { container } </div></> 
                          ​)           
                  ​})
              ​</div>
   ​)
}
```

I am trying to drag and drop button inside "Card" control which is not working but card drag and drop is working and outside the card is also working.

What I am missing ?

Please somebody help

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. There are two ways to solve it.

1. create 2nd drop ref, I mean

   const [, nestedDrop] = useDrop(()=>{ accept, drop, ... }));

use `nestedDrop` inside inner container like this ,

```
​<Card.Body>
     ​<div ref={nestedDrop}></div>
</Card.Body>
```

2. way is inspired from this official example :

   [nested drop area](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/nesting/drop-targets)

you can customize nested dropbox according to your need.